# Freemarker placeholder in html file in Android IDE Template Format

Tags: android, adt, freemarker

I'm working with android studio to develop Android app. I'm working on the creation of a template to use in my applications. I have read the [Android IDE Template Format specification](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/resources-and-tools/6845-android-adt-template-format-document.html#toc_templatexml) and so i start my personal template starting from Dummy template.

I have a .ftl file with the following line of code:

```
<applicationGestureListenerClazz>${projectPackageName}.listeners.${projectShortName}GestureListener</applicationGestureListenerClazz>
```

When i execute the template i obtain the following line:

```
<applicationGestureListenerClazz>org.abubu.dummy.listeners.DummyGestureListener
    </applicationGestureListenerClazz>
```

The variables are correctly defined (in other file they work fine). I don't known why.. it add a CRLF after this line.

Anybody has analogue problem?

**UPDATE**

I discover that the problem is linked to extension of output file. For example. I have a file **license_key_strings.txt.ftl* that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- public key di ${projectPackageName}.key-->
<string name="publicKey">${licenseKey}</string>                          
</resources>
<!-- fine -->
```

If i use it to create a xml file

```
<instantiate    from="root/key/src/main/res/values/license_key_strings.txt.ftl" to="${keyBaseDir}/src/main/res/values/license_key_strings.xml"/>
```

I obtain this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- public key di org.dummy.key-->
    <string name="publicKey">
       MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ
    </string>
</resources>
```

But the output filename ends with .txt

```
<instantiate    from="root/key/src/main/res/values/license_key_strings.txt.ftl" to="${keyBaseDir}/src/main/res/values/license_key_strings.txt"/>
```

The final output become:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- public key di org.dummy.key-->
<string name="publicKey">MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ</string>                     
</resources>
<!-- fine -->
```

I'm working with Android Studio 1.4

Comment: I don't know, but I can tell for sure that FreeMarker itself has no mechanism that would insert a line-break there, in the middle of a static text section.

Comment: i believe it too, but i suspect that there's something how format xml file